# How do I replicate jQuery Quicksand in Windows Forms (or WPF) app?

Tags: c#, jquery, wpf, winforms, silverlight

Hi and thanks for looking!

## Background

I have been developing .NET Web applications for years and am fairly astute in C#, SQL, jQuery, etc but have very little experience with Windows Forms apps and no experience with WPF.

I am now tasked with developing a desktop app which presents a "tiled" list view of media (photos, video thumbnails, etc) to the user.  This list must be searchable, filterable, etc. and uses an XML file as a datasource.

## Problem

I can't figure out how to present a tiled view of objects to the user and have it behave like the jQuery Quicksand plugin, which I have used often in web apps.  Here is an example:

http://razorjack.net/quicksand/

## Question

What is the most expedient way to accomplish a UI, like Quicksand, in a Windows desktop app and should I use WPF or regular Windows Forms?  Also, are there any samples or project file templates online that are similar or at least a good start?  I have been searching but am not finding much.

Many thanks!

Matt

Comment: from my first impression, you could use a WPF `WrapPanel` with a custom `ItemTemplate`... 
you'll have a lot more possibilities of making it look nice in WPF, just remember a new technology (wpf+xaml) always takes a bit of effort to learn...

Comment: Effort.  Boooo.  Ok, ok.  I know I need to buckle down here.  Any good WPF beginners tutorials that you would recommend?  I can google that myself, but if you know of a good one please let me know.  Thanks codesparkle!

Comment: Well, there's [this blog](http://www.wpftutorial.net/LearnWPFin14Days.html) it sounds good but I haven't read it myself, just other things from that site. [This extensive book](http://www.amazon.com/Pro-WPF-2010-Matthew-MacDonald/dp/1430272058/) has helped a **lot**.

Comment: Thanks codesparkle!  I have just ordered the book from Amazon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you presented Silverlight, look into Silverlight 5's (four has it but its much rougher) [PivotViewer Control](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/pivot-viewer/pivotviewer-control) to see if that is of use.

Comment: Thanks Omegaman!  This looks very promising.  I want to test it before selecting this answer as correct so that I don't mislead anyone else who comes across this post.  Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, get all the answers as you can. Just remember that learning Xaml whether for Silverlight, WPF, WPF-XPAB or Windows 8 metro is a good cross over skill.

Comment: @Omegaman-Thanks again for your suggestion, but I had a heck of a time getting all of the dependencies lined up to even use this control and then ran into problems deploying it.  No doubt, this is due to my own ignorance in the realm of WPF and Silverlight, but for now, I am leaving this question open in hopes that someone can provide an answer, in code, that just relies on, say, buttons added dynamically to a wrappanel.